# That's What SHE Said!

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

Bob and Alice were talking about their friend Jenny. Alice was asking Bob why...

> Jenny bought an item for 6 dollars, then she carefully placed it in the trash.
>  She was not angry, disheartened, or sad; 
> she did not eat anything in between;
>  nor did she use it in between.

Just then, Jenny came walking over and said that she was buying ______.

**What did she say?**

*Not a lottery ticket or scratch off

Comment: What can you sit on, sleep on, and brush your teeth with?

Comment: @Anthony A toothbrush? Nobody said sitting on it or sleeping on it was normal, but you certainly can do it :P

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 So close. "A chair, a bed, and a toothbrush".

Comment: Gah. implicit assumption it was a single item :P good call.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300: I'm confused, *isn't* "what can you do X, Y, and Z with" necessarily a single item? Like if you substitute three things the sentence would be clearly ill-formed: *"A chair, a bed, and a toothbrush is something you can sit on, sleep on, and brush your teeth with."*

Comment: @Mehrdad - I'm going to New York next week. Where should I go for the best pizza, bagels, and comedy?

Comment: Oh, and I've been meaning to ask you: what is your favorite book, movie, and snack?

Comment: @Anthony: (Oops, was meaning to reply to you and not Ruadhan2300, thanks for replying.) Hm, yeah, those sentences do allow multiple responses. But I'm not convinced that implies the earlier example must too. Can you give me another similar example where (a) verbs being factored out rather than nouns, and [ideally] (b) the entity of interest would be the subject of the response rather than the object?

Comment: You are assuming (because the riddle works based on the implicit assumption) that there is an implied "what [is *something* that] you can …". I could just as easily argue that the original question is valid, and the response had an implied "a chair, a bed, and a toothbrush, [*respectively*]". Here's one with verbs : Where should I eat, sleep, and park my car while I'm in town? Or (not verbs, but adjectives): what is the hottest, coldest, and most populated city in the US?

Comment: In all of these examples I would say that grammatically they ask for a single answer. The Breadbox Pizzeria/Bakery shop does stand-up comedy on tuesdays might be a suitable answer :P From the context, it becomes clear that multiple answers are _required_ but with the unspoken preface that "I don't know anywhere which does all of them at once but..."

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks for the examples. Again, I admit those work fine. In all honesty, for some reason I just can't accept that those are equivalent to the example above: if you had simply reworded your exact same question to "Where can I dine in, sleep in, and park my car in?" a response with 3 different places wouldn't have been valid (at least to me). I can't put my finger on exactly what it is. It seems possible that the use of a preposition ("on", "in", etc.) that makes this happen (but you're welcome to give me a counterexample with that too). Maybe this is a good question for English.SE..?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

She just bought

> a bunch of trash bags

EDIT : 2nd answer for fun (solely based on the fact that there is a "situation" tag. Be prepared for a really convoluted answer)

jenny was buying

> time

because the situation is the following :

> Jenny is friend with Alice and Bob who don't know each other. She thinks that the two would be a perfect match so she arranged for them to meet. In order for the two to break the ice, she decided to leave them both alone for a short time, so she pretexted to go buy something. She just took the first thing that she saw in the shop (which happened to cost $6). 
> But once jenny got out of the shop she realized that she bought something really useless and just threw it with the trash. Unfortunately, Jenny's plan miserably failed because instead of getting to know each other, Alice and Bob just spoke about Jenny's weird behavior.

Comment: Yep, that is right.

Comment: I like the edit alternative!

Comment: Why would you put this item (plural) in the trash?

Comment: @JBentley that's where [tag:lateral-thinking] comes in place, I did not take "placed carefully in the trash" litterally like in "throwing in the trash", but as doing something with the trash and the object. And since from the 3 last lines i deduced that the object was actually meant to be used with trash it seemed like a reasonable answer

Comment: We understood that. Our question is why would they place a **bunch** of trash bags in the trash (at once).

Comment: I agree, the riddle says "she carefully placed *it* in the trash" not "them". So if she bought multiple bags: a) she will have eaten before using the second bag, b) she will have used "it" (the first trash bag) before before placing "it" (any subsequent trash bag). I feel like the clue that it costs $6 is really just to make it intentionally harder, not clever-er.

Comment: @JBentley Yup, even when double-bagging bins, the whole roll of bin liners isn't usually deployed at once.

Comment: @Kant1 Yes, you __did__ take it _litterally_ (because you thought that it was _litter_)

Comment: Some people keep a whole stack of still-folded trash bags on the bottom of the trash can (under the current liner) to save a trip to the supply closet when it's time to change to a new one.  This also explains why you'd have to place "carefully" (to avoid upsetting the stack) and why $6 is a reasonable amount.

Answer (score 14):

She was buying

> [$6 air fresheners](https://www.etsy.com/listing/525513298/air-fresheners?gpla=1&gao=1&&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping_us_e-home_and_living-other&utm_custom1=1620889d-90ef-409f-a374-620ecd5f5431&gclid=Cj0KCQjwl7nYBRCwARIsAL7O7dEYOVrL4s7GEJdhRAa7Z1sB0uVu_AdqNj44dAknyjJs3rCsJv8fhgAaAi16EALw_wcB)

Answer (score 13):

She bought

> **Easter eggs**, one of which she cleverly hid in the trash. No one will think to look in there!

Comment: Ha ha +1  That is an expensive Easter egg!

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I think the other answer is also expensive at that unit price.

Comment: Hmm I guess. But they were deluxe bags of course.

Comment: @noedne, I was thinking exactly the same thing, so much so that I actually checked the other item’s prices on Amazon. Turns out that out the things are pretty expensive really. (It’s actually pretty common to place the roll at the bottom of the bin, since you usually only need the roll whenever you have removed the previous liner from the bin.)

Comment: @Bass Ahh, I did not think of her doing that with the item.

Answer (score 8):

She bought

> A cinema ticket (or any ticket that allow an entry to something and that you can throw once you pass the door)

An other answer could be

> She bought something from a charity, she didn't really care what it was and she threw it, but she was happy to help the charity

Comment: I guess this would count as having used the item, though.

Comment: hmmm, you are probably right, I would have answered "a drink", but I assume that as she didn't eat, she didn't drink either

Comment: Drinking would probably also count as using.

Answer (score 8):

She bought a

> Spring-loaded Snake as a gag to scare her garbage collector.

Comment: hahaha, very funny!

Answer (score 6):

In the past, Jenny has frequently had several trivial home problems.
She likes to cook, and in the process, discards organic waste in her trash. On several occasions recently, her trash has leaked out onto the pavement outside her house.

Jenny has two roommates who have night shifts, but Jenny has a morning shift. As such, she has to wake up early, cook breakfast, and go to work. In the process, there is a lot of noise, and she has, on occasion, accidentally woken up her roommates.

A couple of days ago, her trash can broke because she threw something into it from far. She regrets it now but her new trash can hasn't arrived in her mail yet.

> Oh well. So she bought a waterproof, non-sound-making, sturdy (not easily tearing) trash bag that she carefully placed inside her trash can for the upcoming few days.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Very interesting, *detailed* response. While it's true that in some corner of the universe this could have been the intended answer, the *actual* intended answer has already been given, like 5 hours ago. Why not take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and familiarize yourself with the site? You'll get a badge for doing so. I look forward to seeing your future contributions.

Comment: ...and I always get *my* non-sound-making, not-easily-tearing trash bags via mail order, FYI.

Answer (score 5):

She was buying

> A lottery ticket

Comment: Nope, she was not sad putting it in. So she did not lose.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie For the record, I never get angry, disheartened, or sad at losing lottery tickets. =p I expect to lose and just try to enjoy the scratching.

Comment: The scratching is pretty entertaining :D. But I said she did not use the object in between.

Answer (score 4):

As many people, Jenny faces the problem of

> not having enough space in her house.

So because

> the last available space in her house is an yet unused trash bin - which she bought a year ago but never needed (she has another one for actual trash) - she now uses it as a container for her stuff.

The item she was buying was

> whatever stuff you can buy for 6 dollars and put in a trash bin. Maybe it's just [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075WPLCHP) [of](http://www.stupid.com/Handi-Panda.html) [those](https://www.ebay.com/sch/USB-Flash-Drives/51071/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=DSLR%20Camera%20USB%20Drive) [things](https://www.ebay.com/sch/USB-Lights-Gadgets/67870/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=USB%20Fan%20Clock) [you](https://techunder10.com/collections/tech/products/50-year-calendar) [buy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075MHB4G6) [because](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DZJF95Y) [they](https://www.thinkgeek.com/product/kinr/) [seem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000TTNW98) [cool](http://www.stupid.com/Smiley-Emoji-Pong-Balls.html) and then put anywhere and forget forever (would match Jenny's style here). Or maybe it's food for her cat and she didn't manage to find a good other place for it. Or [put anything here]...

This answer also explains why she placed the item

> carefully

in the trash.

Answer (score 3):

She bought:

> Food for homeless people in alleyways behind the house.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!  Could you elaborate on your answer? - how does it answer all the parts (specifically, when did she place her purchase in the trash)?

Comment: She doesn't have to use the food. If it's pre-prepared, she could put it out without even unwrapping it.

Comment: Why put it in the trash instead of just handing it over, though? lol